# Intraday table for Firebase Analytics in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

Google Analytics for Firebase link to BigQuery.
My Firebase Project send the app log data over 950,000 records to BigQuery in a day.
BigQuery has two intraday tables for the past two days.
And  yesterday intraday table has disappear around noon and archived for events table.

The document shows that intraday table is shown only today.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512

But why BigQuery has two intraday tables for the past two days? Do my setting is something wrong? 
Or does it just takes a time to process the daily log which is large?

I would like to know it is right behavior for BigQuery.
If not so,  I think my linking setting Firebase to BigQuery is something wrong.

I Attached two intraday tables for the past two days.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnmAH.png)

Best Regards,

Comment: Firebase somehow let to live together those two intraday tables (BigQuery cannot change by himself the data, it needs a request from the client, in this case Firebase). I would think that this is expected under certain circumstances as both intraday tables have their own sufix  '_YYYYMMDD' (e.g. the process required more time because of large data, or a condition was not met until certain time). I would recommend you monitor the BigQuery logs to check if something failed in the BQ side (an error can lead us to the root case) or Firebase simply sent the load intraday request late.

Comment: There was some outage recently (~1 week ago). I had 3 intraday tables stuck. Firebase support confirmed that there are other reports about same issue. 2 days after it was resolved "by itself".

Comment: Can you clarify if you have intraday tables for current day and yesterday? Or yesterday and the day before yesterday?